# Autoscroll vertical table html

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have this scroller for a table. I would like him to continue scrolling at the end Continuing from the first field. The table is dynamic, so when there are few fields it doesn't have to scroll.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
            pic_scroll:function (){
                $(this).each(function(){
                    var _this=$(this);
                    var ul=_this.find("table");
                    var li=ul.find("tbody");
                    var w=li.size()*li.outerHeight();
                    var i=1,l;
                    _this.hover(function(){i=0},function(){i=1});
                    function autoScroll(){
                        l = _this.scrollTop();
                        if(l>=w){
                            _this.scrollTop(0);
                        }else{
                            _this.scrollTop(l + i);
                        }
                    }
                    var scrolling = setInterval(autoScroll,30);
                })
            }
        });
        $(function(){
            $(".contain").pic_scroll();
        })
```

How can I do? With this code arrived at the end it stops and that's it.

Thanks

Comment: What is _"by putting those initials"_ supposed to mean?

Comment: Continuing from the first field

Comment: Usually slider scripts _clone_ elements, so that they can show a copy of the first item(s), when the element has been scrolled all the way - because other than that, a _continuous_ scroll can usually not be achieved in the first place. Whether that even makes sense when you are scrolling a table ... you'd have to try and see.

Comment: I tried. But with a few fields I only get that it stops and doubles the result.

Comment: You need to find the right point to "reset" it again, so that the first item gets shown at the very left again.

Comment: And how do you reset?

Comment: You probably want to call `_this.scrollTop(0)` at some point again.